# JOOQ generator: use existing enums

Tags: jooq, jooq-codegen

I am using `nu.studer.jooq` gradle plugin to generate pojos, tables and records for a PostgreSQL database with tables that have fields of type `ENUM`.
We already have the enums in the application, so I would like that the generator uses those enums instead of generating new ones.
I defined in build.gradle for the generator: `udts = false`, so it doesn't generate the enums, and I wrote a custom generator strategy that sets the package for the enums to be the one of the already existing enums.
I have an issue in the generated table fields, the `SQLDataType.VARCHAR.asEnumDataType(mypackage.ExistingEnum)` doesn't work because the `mypackage.ExistingEnum` does not implement `org.jooq.EnumType`.

```
public enum ExistingEnum {
    VAL1, VAL2
}
```

Generated table record:

```
public class EntryTable extends TableImpl<EntryRecord> {
    public final TableField<EntryRecord, ExistingEnum> MY_FIELD = createField(DSL.name("my_field"), SQLDataType.VARCHAR.asEnumDataType(mypackage.ExistingEnum.class), this, "");

}
```

Is there something I can do to fix this issue? Also we have a lot of enums, so writing a converter for each of them is not suitable.

Answer (score 0):

The point of having custom enum types is that they are individual types, independent of whatever you encode with your database enum types. As such, the jOOQ code generator cannot make any automated assumptions related to how to map the generated types to the custom types. [You'll have to implement `Converter` types of some sort](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-forced-types/).

If you're not relying on the jOOQ provided `EnumType` types, you could use the  [`<enumConverter/>` configuration](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-forced-types/codegen-database-forced-types-enum-converter/), or write implementations based on [`org.jooq.impl.EnumConverter`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/dev/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/EnumConverter.html), which help reduce boilerplate code.

If you have some conventions or rules how to map things a bit more automatically (just because jOOQ doesn't know your convention doesn't mean you don't know it either), you could implement a [programmatic code generation configuration](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-programmatic/), where you query your dictionary views (e.g. `PG_CATALOG.PG_ENUM`) to generate `ForcedType` objects. You can even use jOOQ-meta for that purpose.

Comment: I am trying to use the programmatic code generation configuration: `new ForcedType()
    .withUserType("mypkg.ExistingEnum")
    .withEnumConverter(false)
    .withBinding("mypkg.EnumBinding")
    .withTypes("existing_enum")`

However the generated table record still has `SQLDataType.VARCHAR.asEnumDataType()` which fails because the existing enums don't implement `EnumType`. It seems that the `JavaGenerator` always adds that method call. Can I remove it? Also how can I query my dictionary views? Through a separate jdbc connection?

Comment: created a test repo here: https://github.com/jarasez/JooqGenerator

Comment: @jarasez: You should convert between the jOOQ generated enum type and your own one, not between String and your own type.

Comment: isn't it possible to not generate Jooq enums at all? They have the same name and fields, the only difference is that my own does not implement EnumType

Comment: @jarasez: jOOQ still needs the `EnumType` for its type name and qualification information in order to generate correct SQL. The generated SQL requires casts such as `cast(? as schema.enum_type)` to work correctly. Why does it bother you?